# How do I print just the first and second element of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array called tagline that looks like this:

```
[" Leger Poll", " Web survey of 2", "test", "test", "test", "test"]
```

it is pulled from an external **CSS** file. I have assigned it a variable name `tagline`.

I want to print the first and second elements using `document.getElementById` so that I can style the text. I am not sure why this is not working? I tried pulling the variable outside of the main function so that it would be global but still not working. I am a beginner coder. Here is what I have. Please help.

````
    var tagline = [];


    async function getData() {
      // const response = await fetch('testdata.csv');
      var response = await fetch('data/test3.csv');
      var data = await response.text();
      data = data.replace(/"/g, "");
      var years = [];
      var vals = [];

      var rows = data.split('\n').slice(1);

      rows = rows.slice(0, rows.length - 1);
      rows = rows.filter(row => row.length !== 0)

      rows.forEach(row => {
        var cols = row.split(",");
        years.push(cols[0]);
        vals.push(0 + parseFloat(cols[1]));
        tagline.push(cols[2]);
      });

      console.log(years, vals, tagline);
      return { years, vals, tagline };


    }
    var res = tagline.slice(1);
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = res;
    var res2 = tagline.slice(2);
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = res2;


  </script> ```
````

Comment: Can you show us results from testdata.csv and expected values for demo1 and demo2?

Comment: You never call `getData`? But even if you did: you cannot expect a future result to be available now.

Comment: You never call the function `getData()`. Even if you did, it's in an asynchronous request. The rest of your JS code is synchronous, so it will be executed before the request has finished and the array has any data. You should look into using a `Promise`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems You defined the function `getData()` but you didn't call it to execute.

Since you use **Async** function, I am using `then()`.

```
var tagline = [];

async function getData() { ...// your function }

getData().then(() => {

    const res = tagline[0];
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = res;

    const res2 = tagline[1];
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = res2;

});
```

Comment: The tagline.slice returns an array!

Comment: The array returns this in my console Trincot  [" Leger Poll", " Web survey of 2", "test", "test", "test", "test"]

Comment: I am feeling confused. Sorry I am just a beginner. I just want to display on my web page the first two elements of the array (in col3)that comes in from the csv data. I have the array coming in correctly but I can't get it to print to the console.

Comment: BigPiggie. Are you saying I should make another function inside the async function to print? Like this?
getData().then(() => {

    const res = tagline[0];
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = res;

    const res2 = tagline[1];
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = res2;

}

Comment: This worked. THANK YOU BadPiggie!!! You are the bomb!!! 

Comment: @TamTaminToronto Sorry for the late response. I recommend you go through this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 1):

To access a specific index of an array use:

```
array[index];
```

In your case:

```
tagline[0]; //first element
tagline[1]; //second element
```

Since the `getData` is `async` you must `await` for it to fill the `tagline`:

```
await getData(); //call it before you use the tagline array
```

If you are using an older version of JS which does not support `async/await` you need to wait for the promise response with `.then`.

Also, be aware:

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
> into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included)
> where start and end represent the index of items in that array.

Comment: Please read the entire question before providing the answer.

Comment: @BadPiggie What part did I miss??!

Comment: You missed that their array is empty... And if this really were the answer, then surely it is a duplicate question and you should vote to close. Look at the comments below the question.

Comment: @AmirMB please mention the version of JS because older versions do not support top-level `await`.  `await` need to be used inside `async`

Comment: @BadPiggie the OP marked the question as async. That's why I assumed he is using ECMAScript 2017

Comment: No. except for the ECMA Modules, You need to use `await` inside an `async` function. So better if you wrap it with an `async` function or use `then`

Comment: @BadPiggie my bad

Comment: BigPiggie I am attempting your "then" suggestion. Do I put this function after the async function or inside it?